# Deploying J2ME midlet on BlackBerry using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me

I have a small J2ME midlet program and it is running fine in eclipse with J2ME plugin. I want to deploy the same on BlackBerry using eclipse. But I cant find any resource for the same. I have a tutorial doing this using Websphere studio device developer IDE. I cannot find its free download link either. Anyone can suggest how to achieve this deployment using Eclipse? If not, is Websphere studio available for free?

Comment: such inappropriate Tags might results into down voting . please avoid (Edited now)

Answer (score 0):

You could install the BlackBerry Plugin for Eclipse and create a new BlackBerry project, copy or import your existing source from the J2ME project and then use the Plugins debug and deploy your application the the BlackBerry simulator or device.